# 'AttributeError' : Object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

Error :

```
AttributeError at / 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I am not able to debug this error! I overlooked my codes many times, but can't able to understand where is the error being generated. Please be helping me. Thanks in advance.

**forms.py**

```py
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.PasswordInput()
    password2 = forms.PasswordInput()


    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password Should Match')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**views.py**

```py
def userview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = User(username=username,email=email,password =password1)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponse('User Created')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':form})
```

template
**home.html**

```html
<form method="post" id="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
<input type='submit' value ='ok'>
</form>
```

**project level `urls.py`**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('useradd.urls'))
]
```

**app level `urls.py`**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.UserForm,name = 'useradd')

]
```

Full Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'useradd']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner 35.             
response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__ 97.             
response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response 26.         
if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

As instructed I have provided a full traceback of this error. I think I have defined the post method in `views.py` and when the method is not posted then it will access the else part of the function. But still can't understand why such errors occur.

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner sir as instructed i have added the traceback

Comment: Can you add urls.py file also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner yeah sir, have added now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proble in your urls. Instead of view, you are passing form to the url, it should be this:

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.userview,name = 'useradd')

]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the class UserForm has no method or variable called as get. You need to define one first.